# By default, how much space is reserved for OP/Wear-Leveling on a typical SSD?

Tags: ssd

For a typical SSD, how much "extra/hidden" space is reserved for overprovisioning/wear-leveling etc. This is assuming no extra space has been allocated for this purpose by the user themselves. I am looking for a percentage answer.

Comment: That might be info left in the darkness, unless you find a datasheet telling that much.

Comment: "typical" isn't really specific enough. Even the consumer market includes a wide range spanning cheap crappy OEM SSDs, nicer MLC or SLC devices, high-capacity QLC devices that save cost, high-capacity QLC devices that use large reserves to be able to compete with non-QLC devices, etc. (FWIW I don't have a percentage answer; I work on datacenter storage so the numbers I have are under NDA and even in *our* case if a coworker asked about our "typical" SSDs I'd ask them to clarify)

Comment: @nanofarad understandable. Talking in very vague terms then, let's say for crappy OEM SSDs, would you expect a percentage over ~30% ?

Comment: @havethegrace All of my knowledge on SSDs is based on proprietary info (I work on a team that designs portions of a major tech company's SSD storage) so I'll have to recuse myself from answering unless I can find a public source I can cite and quote from directly. With that said, the cheaper and crappier the SSD, the more cost savings (hence likely less OP space) and hence less lifetime/reliability. 30% also seems a bit high, especially for this lower end market. You might be able to use SMART to get a count of reserved blocks for the SSD you already have.

Comment: @nanofarad thanks, I'll give that a go.

Comment: @havethegrace could you clarify whether you really only care about the space needed for wear leveling, or whether you're generally interested in the ratio of bits available to the user to bits of the physical storage medium?

Answer (score 2):

The term "over provisioning" has two meanings:

1. The amount of user-accessible space that the manufacturer advises
   leaving unused to optimize disk performance.
   This amount is usually said to be 30%.
2. The amount of space that is only visible to the firmware and is
   intended for mapping bad sectors.

This second amount depends largely on the disk size and the amount
of expected usage:

- The larger (and costlier) the disk, the more space is allocated
  (probably to avoid user dissatisfaction)
- The more intense the expected usage, the more space is allocated
  to avoid the too-early failure of the disk.

The Kingstone Technology article
[Understanding SSD Over-provisioning (OP)](https://www.kingston.com/france/en/ssd/overprovisioning)
has this table relating to Kingston SSDs:

[image]

The normal amount for small disks for normal usage is about 7%.
But this goes up quickly for large disks and ones that are intended
for intense usage to 14% and even 28%.

Disks that are marked for "Read Intensive" get only 7%,
except for the largest SSD of 2TB which gets 14%.

Disks that are marked for "More Write Intensive" get 28%,
no matter their size. I suppose that such disks may be said to be of
"Enterprise" quality when marketed.

These numbers are for Kingstone SSDs, but I would assume that most SSD
manufacturers follow similar guidelines (except perhaps for the
very cheapest ones).

Answer (score 1):

**Samsung**

> How do I calculate the OP ratio?
>
> OP Ratio Formula: OP (%) = ((Physical Capacity – User Capacity) / User Capacity) * 100
>
> Ex) When 120 GB of a 128 GB SSD is used as the user capacity while 8 GB is assigned to the OP, the OP (%) is ((128 – 120) / 120) *
> 100 = 6.7 %.

[Source: page #3](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/global.semi.static/S190311-SAMSUNG-Memory-Over-Provisioning-White-paper.pdf)

---

**Seagate**

> For example, a 128GB SSD will inherently include 128 * 73,741,824 = 94.4 million bytes of built-in over-provisioning.

[Source: Amount of Over-provisioning](https://www.seagate.com/tech-insights/ssd-over-provisioning-benefits-master-ti/)

---

**Intel**

[image]

[Source: page #2](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/over-provisioning-nand-based-ssds-better-endurance-whitepaper.pdf)

*PDF did not allow copy+pasting*

Answer (score 1):

That number will not be *that* high. What will be significant will be the redundancy in the ECC, and that percentage depends fully on the physical properties of the flash memory, the acceptable bit error rate visible to the user, and the capabilities of the flash controller.

To explain: Every medium, no matter whether storage or transfer, has an error probability. Hence, you need error-correcting codes that work under the hood to make it looks like perfect bits go in, perfect bits come out of the medium.

Flash memory is really a playground for high-tech coding. Flash cost per byte is dominated by the ability to store many bits on a given area. Hence, the floating gate capacitors that actually physically store the information get ever smaller. Also, most modern flash uses multiple charge levels to store more than 1 bit per cell.

All that makes errors more likely. However, at the same time, error-correction decoders have gotten better. A rate 0.99 code (i.e. in 10000 bits  of raw storage, you store 9900 actual information bits) can do much more than 10 years ago. But these units are very much what higher-end SSD controler companies compete over.

So, no general rule can be given: A consumer SSD might have a different acceptable error rate, a different acceptable speed, and a different acceptable cost than a SSD for corporate database usage – or a different latency budget than a SSD for highest-rate recording. That together with technological progress:

Expect any answer to your question to be meaningless without saying exactly what the SSD is. Anything between 0.1% and 100% overhead is plausible, depending on use case.

Now, you don't ask about coding, you ask about wear leveling. Expect numbers around one fourth for your store-bought nvme SSDs, or much less. It's a very easy knob to adjust the cost/size tradeoff for your SSD, and so I expect cheaper OEMs to use different configurations than people targetting prosumer storage needs.

Comment: None of this answer seems in any way related to the question until the last paragraph...

Comment: @BenVoigt I inferred from the question that the asker was interested in how much larger than the storage capacity the memory would have to be ("over-provisioned"), not solely in the amount spent on wear leveling "reserve"; but I do agree, only the last paragraph addresses the "wear-levelling".

Comment: I've never heard "over-provisioned" used in a way that includes encoding overhead (which is inside each block).  It's always been the number of spare entire blocks, whether used for wear-leveling or write cache (to reduce write-amplification).

Comment: @BenVoigt no, coding doesn't happen only within blocks. Modern LDPC codes as used by storage media are > 10000 bits in size. I've just went ahead and asked in a comment, it makes little sense for the two of us to speculate when we can just ask :)